# extra characters are printed when file contents are read into a array in c

Tags: c

I just want to read a file and store it in a array.
I tried the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fcntl.h> 
int main()
{
int fd;
char buffer[500];
fd=open("input.txt",O_RDONLY);
read(fd,buffer,500);
printf("\nTHE FILE CONTENTS ARE:\n%s",buffer);
}
```

input.txt contains:

```
COPY   START 0000  
FIRST  STL   RETADR  
CLOOP  JSUB  RDREC  
       LDA   LENGTH  
       COMP  #0 
       JEQ   ENDFIL  
       JSUB  WRREC  
       J     CLOOP 
ENDFIL LDA   =C'EOF'  
       STA   BUFFER  
       LDA   #3  
       STA   LENGTH  
       JSUB  WRREC  
       J     @RETADR  
       USE   CDATA  
       RETADR RESW  1
       LENGTH RESW  
       USE   CBLKS
       BUFFER RESB 4096
       BUFEND EQU   *
       MAXLEN EQU    BUFEND-BUFFER
```

when i printing i am getting extra characters at the end.

end line that i get is

MAXLEN EQU  BUFEND-BUFFER EQU  BUFEND-BUFFER

why is this?how to solve?

Comment: [This](http://linux.die.net/man/3/read) may be helpful to you. In particular, "If the value of nbyte is greater than {SSIZE_MAX}, the result is implementation-defined.". I would suggest doing something such as using the return value of `read()` to detect when your buffer has not been fully filled, and handle that case specially, as I imagine your problem has to do with your buffer being filled with junk that isn't overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a buffer overflow in your code. You fill the `char buffer[500];` argument with 500 characters from the file, but then you `printf` it with `%s`, which expects a zero-terminated string. But `buffer` is not zero-terminated, hence `printf` will try to read `buffer[500]`, `buffer[501]`, etc until it finds a zero terminator (`'\0'` ).

I suggest you define `buffer` to be 501 characters long, fill it with 500 characters and set `buffer[500]` to `'\0'` so that `printf` will not attempt to read past `buffer[500]`.

**Edit:** Actually to print only the contents read from the file you should check the return value of the `read` call and put the `'\0'` character next to last character written into `buffer`, e.g.:

```
int fd;
char buffer[501];
fd = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY);
const ssize_t r = read(fd, buffer, 500);
if (r < 0) {
    // Handle error
} else {
    buffer[r] = '\0';
    printf("\nTHE FILE CONTENTS ARE:\n%s",buffer);
}
```

See the manual page for `read` for more information (`man 3p read`).

Comment: still getting the same output

Comment: That is simply not possible. Time to learn how to use a debugger.